# Why is there a separation between Luke and Acts?

Tags: luke, acts, new-testament, canonicity

Even though there are still some discussions on that, Luke is widely recognized as the author of the book of Acts. Wikenhauser-Schmid (Einleitung, 376) list the following modern interpreters who recognize that: Dibelius, E. Meyer, T. W. Manson, Streeter, von Campenhausen, Eltester, Trocmé, van Unnik, Klijn, McNeile, and Bauernfeind.

I wonder, however, why is there a separation between the gospel of Luke and the book of Acts, something that tends to obscure the second-volume character of Acts?

Comment: If youre asking about authorship or why there are 2 volumes by Luke; gospel and Acts, instead of a combined one?

Comment: @Michael16 the second part of your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the book *The Text of the New Testament: Its Transmission, Corruption, and Restoration* by Metzger and Ehrman, chapter 1, The making of ancient books, page 11-12:

> In the Greco-Roman world, literary works were customarily
> published in the format of a scroll, made of papyrus or parchment.
> The papyrus scroll was made by gluing together, side by side, separate
> sheets of papyrus and then winding the long strip around a
> roller, thus producing a volume (a word derived from the Latin
> volumen, "something rolled up"). The length of a papyrus roll was
> limited by considerations of convenience in handling it; the normal Greek literary roll seldom exceeded 35 feet in length. Ancient authors therefore would divide a long literary work into several "books," each of which could be accommodated in one roll. The two longest books in the New Testament, the Gospel of Luke and the
> Book of Acts, would each have filled an ordinary papyrus roll of 31
> or 32 feet in length. Doubtless, this is one of the reasons why Luke
> and Acts were issued in two volumes instead of one.